# Office.js: How to get a property from an item derived from a collection (e.g., 'address' property of all Ranges in a NamedItemCollection) in a batch

Tags: excel, office-js

I have a workbook with 2000 Named Ranges.  I want to get range properties like the address, columnCount, rowCount and perhaps the cell values object.  I can get these with 2000 server calls.  This is ok in Excel, but not in Excel Online (2000 server roundtrips).
I want to get properties like 'address' with just a couple batch operations?
I've tried various combinations like the below (does not work), but cannot figure out how.

```
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var nameditems = ctx.workbook.names;
        nameditems.load('items');
        return ctx.sync().then(function () {
            var nameditemsProperties = nameditems.load('address, rowCount');
            return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < nameditemsProperties.items.length; i++) {
                    app.showNotification('address: ' + nameditemsProperties.getItem[i].address);
                }
            });
        })
    }).catch(function (error) {
        handleErrors(error);
    });
```

Can I (How can I) get properties like 'address' in an array with just a couple batch operations?
I'm using Excel API 1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close... but you need to do the loading on the Range object.

You can still do it with just 2 syncs.  First one to get all the named items, second one to load the addresses of each of the named items.

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var nameditems = ctx.workbook.names.load('name');
    var namesToRanges = {};
    return ctx.sync()
        .then(function () {
            nameditems.items.forEach(function (item) {
                namesToRanges[item.name] = item.getRange().load("address");
            })
        })
        .then(ctx.sync)
        .then(function () {
            nameditems.items.forEach(function (item) {
                console.log(item.name, namesToRanges[item.name].address);
            })
        })
})
.catch(function (error) {
    OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
});
```

For what it's worth, you will get better IntelliSense and easier-to-read code if you use TypeScript:

```
async function run() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
            const nameditems = ctx.workbook.names.load('name');
            const namesToRanges: { [name: string]: Excel.Range } = {};
            await ctx.sync()
            nameditems.items.forEach(function (item) {
                namesToRanges[item.name] = item.getRange().load("address");
            })
            await ctx.sync();
            nameditems.items.forEach(function (item) {
                console.log(item.name, namesToRanges[item.name].address);
            })
        });
    } catch (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    }
}
```

You can find some info on using TypeScript with Office.js in the e-book "[Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins/)".  Full disclosure: I am the author of said book, but I can pretty well guarantee you will find a lot of useful material there, both with regards to using TypeScript, and about the Office.js patterns in general.

**UPDATE: updating code to allow for non-range Named Items as well:**

```
$("#run").click(run);

async function run() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
            const nameditems = ctx.workbook.names.load('name, type, value');
            const namesToValues: { [name: string]: Excel.Range | any } = {};
            await ctx.sync()

            nameditems.items.forEach(item => {
                if (item.type === Excel.NamedItemType.range) {
                    namesToValues[item.name] = item.getRange().load("address");
                } else {
                    namesToValues[item.name] = item.value;
                }
            });

            await ctx.sync();

            nameditems.items.forEach(item => {
                const value = namesToValues[item.name];
                console.log(item.name,
                    (value instanceof Excel.Range) ? value.address : value);
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably what I need, but I'm getting {"code":"InvalidOperation","message":"This operation is not permitted for the current object.","errorLocation":"NamedItem.getRange"}

Comment: It does work.  The reason I got the errors above is because I was trying to get range properties (like 'address') of items that were not valid ranges.  When I filter them out, I am able to get all of the properties I need (including the range values) of all my valid namedRanges with just 2 syncs.

Comment: If you want to make the code safer, just load the "type" as well, and only call getRange on range named-items.  See updated code.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me to get the names and addresses, but not cell values or counts, using 1.4

```
async function run() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            var names = context.workbook.names;
            names.load();
            await context.sync();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(names.items));
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does work for getting the addresses, however, I noticed that the addresses for dynamic ranges are the formula for the range, not the resulting/current range.  Michael's solution provides the resulting range address (as well as many other properties).

Comment: Yes - the current implementation of Named Item (what Excel calls Defined Name) Value gives you the refers-to formula if the Named Item resolves to a range or a scalar value if the named item resolves to a single value or the first value in the array if the named item resolves to an array. Personally I regard this behavior for non-range items as inconsistent and a bug.